# caffe create networks by python

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

We all know this python code can create caffe networks:

```
    n = caffe.NetSpec()
    n.data, n.label = L.Data(batch_size=batch_size,
                             backend=P.Data.LMDB, source=lmdb,
                             transform_param=dict(scale=1. / 255), ntop=2)
    n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=5,
                            num_output=20, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool1 = L.Pooling(n.conv1, kernel_size=2,
                        stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
```

The layer's name is on the right of n. for example:"n.data",this layer's name is "data".

1. Write  simple code

If I want to create much more layers ,and the layers' name are the same except the number. For example, all layers' names are {conv1,conv2,conv3,...,conv100}.
I want to definite a string `s_name = conv%s` and just loop the number to do the same thing for once ,don't need to write almost the same code 100 times.How should I do?

2. add '/' in name?
   The layer's name is "conv1/dw",how could I definite the name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either using `__setattr__`:

```
s_name = 'conv{:03d}'.format(i)
l = L.Convolution( # ...
n.__setattr__(s_name, l)
```

An extensive example (unrolling LSTM units) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35967589/1714410)

Alternatively, you can use the `__getitem__` attribute:

```
n[s_name] = L.Convolution( # ...
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136339/1714410) for more information.