# How to join object and its member in python

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I have a python `caffe object` called `net`.
Normally in python, net was setup for its layer as

```
net.conv1_1 = L.Convolution(net[from_layer], num_output=64, pad=1, kernel_size=3, **kwargs)
```

But for me, I have layer names as variables in the program and not hard coded.
So how I can join layer name conv1 to net. I did as

```
join( net.,'%s'%(layer[lIdx]['l_name']))=L.Convolution(net[layer[lIdx-1]['l_name']], num_output=layer[lIdx]['n_channels'], pad=layer[lIdx]['l_struct'][2], kernel_size=layer[lIdx]['l_struct'][0], **kwargs)
```

This `join( net.,'%s'%(layer[lIdx]['l_name']))` gave me `SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax',`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136339/1714410) using `__getitem__`, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51467840/1714410) using `setattr`:

```
n[layer[lIdx]['l_name']] = L.Convolution( # ...
```

or

```
setattr(n, layer[lIdx]['l_name'], L.Convolution( # ...
```

Python's [`join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) works on strings and produces strings, `net.conv1_1` is not a string: it's `conv1_1` attribute of object `net`.